# Best method for secure socket server implementation?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

I'd like to encrypt packet data over a SSL/TLS connection between a SSL client and server, and I would like to use a simple key that can be generated on the client host and copy/pasted to the server host or visa versa.  They just need to use the same key to encrypt/decrypt the data.  It needs to be reasonably secure, but not over the top.  I am not that concerned about man in the middle attacks, and probably don't need authentication at this time.  I just need encryption.

I am assuming that I need a method to generate a shared private key.  What are the best choices available?

New info:  I am trying to replace an existing implementation that I inherited.  The existing implementation uses openssl SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_SINGLE_DH_USE) and SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh(ctx, get_dh512()) to encrypt / decrypt the data on both ends.  What I am trying to do is replace the fixed DH stuff with something more flexible.  From the responses, it sounds like I had better just stick with public key cryptography.

Comment: If you're already using a SSL connection, why encrypt the data again?

Comment: Also: "shared private key" seems to mean the same as "symmetric encryption". Use AES or Blowfish or Twofish, whichever is available easily on both ends of the connection.

Comment: I guess I am looking for some guidance on setting up the SSL/TLS connection for encryption.  I need both ends to use the same method.  But I don't want it to be a fixed method.  The user should be able to generate a key or something on one end, and apply it to the other end.

Comment: What you are describing is precisely what SSL/TLS does. You do not need to implement it yourself.

Comment: "The user should be able to generate a key or something on one end, and apply it to the other end." Well then you might not looking for SSL or TLS, because that system is based on an infrastructure  of publically trusted certificates. (You can also use private per-connection certificates with SSL but it might be a bit of a chore, it's really not built to do that.)

Comment: Also, why exactly do you need the user to change the key used on a whim?

Comment: And I still don't understand what "reasonably secure but not over the top" even means - what sort of attacks are you trying to prevent or not, and why? (For one I can't understand why you wouldn't be worried about MITM attacks, seeing as they're the easiest way to access data at a point in time when it's the most actionable.)

Comment: Last, but not least, if you're looking for help on programmatically setting up a SSL connection, Google can probably help you.

Comment: Just as easy to generate a self-signed certificate for the server and use a standard public key exchange algorithm as it would be to set up a pre-shared key.

Comment: 'Shared private key' is a contradiction in terms *and* a ***major*** security breach. I think you mean 'shared symmetric key'. If you were going to use PKI there would be two keypairs. SSL is already far more than 'reasonably secure' without whatever you are trying to do, and it is already designed and built. Amateur cryptography tends to be not secure at all. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @millimoose you've got to read about PSK ciphersuites and other alternative mechanisms besides certificates in TLS.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Thanks for the correction, I was mostly extrapolating from a naive understanding of how SSL is used in HTTPS. I guess my greater point was that SSL is a pretty large, complicated technology, and the OP would do better sticking to known ground instead of trying to design his own cryptosystem.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the Pre-Shared Key Ciphersuits described in [RFC 4279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279). It's called `TLS-PSK`. There is an [example](http://tiebing.blogspot.com/2013/09/tls-psk-server-using-openssl-library.html) from Sept. 17, 2013 that claims to have gotten it to work.

I'm not sure why you want to do this, though. It takes a lot of effort to share keys properly.

Comment: It looks like the project was renamed on BitBucket since this blog entry was published: https://bitbucket.org/tiebingzhang/tls-psk-server-client-example